# NullReferenceException when appending attribute to the element in xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, nullreferenceexception, xpath, selectsinglenode

I get a NullReferenceException when trying to append element to its parent to element, like this

```
XmlDocument dartDatabase = new XmlDocument();
string path = @"D:\xml\dartDatabase.xml";
```

...

```
dartDatabase.Load(path);

XmlNode newGame = dartDatabase["games"].AppendChild(dartDatabase.CreateElement("game"));

XmlNode newGameId = dartDatabase.CreateAttribute("id");
newGameId.Value = gameId.ToString();
newGame.Attributes.SetNamedItem(newGameId);
```

...

```
XmlNode existingGame = dartDatabase.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/games/game[@id='gameId']");
XmlNode newPlayer = dartDatabase.CreateElement("player");
existingGame.AppendChild(newPlayer);
//dartDatabase.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(newPlayer, dartDatabase.DocumentElement.LastChild);

XmlNode newPlayerId = dartDatabase.CreateAttribute("id");
newPlayerId.Value = playerId.ToString();
newPlayerId.Attributes.SetNamedItem(newPlayer);
```

There is probably some error in XPath expression, so i tried to append element newPlayer as a lastChild, just to try code that follows. And there too i get NullReferenceException when appending attribute newPlayerId to element newElement. First part works just fine, it create xml file like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <games>
      <game id="2" name="501" />
    </games>
```

but second part, when i try to add newPlayer element to a specific element which i determine by attribute id.

xml file should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <games>
  <game id="2" name="501">
   <player id="1">
   </player>
  </game>
 </games>
```

Comment: `SelectSingleNode("/games/game[@id='gameId']");` - presumably no game has a gameId equal to "gameId"!  `SelectSingleNode("/games/game[@id='" + gameId.ToString() + "']");` is more appropriate.

Comment: i tried like you wrote, and i get same result. And i checked existingGame is null, but newPlayer is not null its value is {Element, player}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectSingleNode` procedure will return `null` as gameId has not been found:

```
dartDatabase.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/games/game[@id='gameId']");
```

Hence `existingGame` is `null` and thus the `NullReferenceException` is thrown when calling:

```
existingGame.AppendChild(newPlayer);
```

You will have to escape the gameId like this:

```
SelectSingleNode("/games/game[@id='" + gameId.ToString() + "']");
```

---

A much easier approach to attributes, XmlElement is more specific.
But you shouldn't try not to go more general unless you can't do it with XmlElement...

```
var existingGame = (XmlElement) doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("...");

existingGame.SetAttribute("id", gameId);
```

Comment: You are right i changed XPath, and it did the trick, existing game is not null now. But second part is still throwing NullReferenceException, when i try to append attribute newPlayerId to newPlayer element

Comment: In the last name you need to swap newPlayerId and newPlayer. Now you're adding the node to the attribute, but you meant to add the attribute to the node...

Comment: Why not just declare newPlayer as an XmlElement and call `SetAttribute("id", playerId.ToString())` on it?

Comment: Cool, didnt see that. In other elements/atribute couples i did the right thing, but missed this one. 

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @Stanislav: What Will A means: You can cast XmlNode's to XmlElement's and then just use setAttribute, I've added an example of how you can use just one line to add an attribute in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that existingGame and newPlayer are both non-null? I'm guessing that `SelectSingleNode` didn't find anything and returned null. (I don't think it's possible for newPlayer to be null, but check just in case.)

Comment: As written, SelectSingleNode _will_ return null!  (the gameid variable isn't substituted, the XPATH just contains its name not its value).

Comment: existingGame is null, and like you said newPlayer is not null its value is {Element, player}